# Guarantees about returning view or copy for Pandas Series operations

Tags: python, pandas

For pandas data structures, returning views or copies sometimes isn't clearcut, and in fact, the doc suggests that it simply isn't known at times, and so it's better not to assume. For example, on [this section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) of the latest official docs, it is implied no assumptions about what `df.loc[:]` returns (view or copy) should be made.

What about simple operations on Series? Consider:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 3, 6])
t = s*2
```

Is there any guarantees about whether `t` is a view or copy of `s`? On my platform with pandas 1.0, `t` appears to be a copy. But I wonder if this is guaranteed.

I haven't dug into the source to figure this out. Or perhaps there is a section of the doc I missed?